# Frequent connection loss on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection, boot-camp

I use Windows 7 on a bootcamp partition (on my macbook). I recently formatted the partition and reinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) (to enlarge the partition). However I'm experiencing frequent internet connection loss and I was unable to track down the error.

I'm pretty sure this is not a router/ISP problem: there are no connection issues when I use macos or when I surf the web with my smartphone.

The loss lasts few seconds (in most of the cases less than a minute). During this period I have a yellow warning sign on the wifi icon, saying "No internet connection". I still have access to the router, so the issue should not be related to some kind of wifi sleep mode (which I disabled anyway, just to be sure).

I disabled the IPv6 option (in the connection properties) as I read it may cause some issue sometimes. Windows Firewall is disabled either and I have no antivirus. I also installed all the system updates, but the connection issue remained. And, of course, I installed the bootcamp drivers (otherwise I couldn't connect at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

1. If possible, connect your computer directly to the router via a network cable (so Windows can download a replacement driver if necessary)
2. Open Device Manager (search for it, or find it in the Control Panel category Hardware and Sound)
3. Expand Network Adapters, and locate the entry for your wireless adapter (example Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter).  Right-click it, and choose Uninstall.
4. Check the box that reads "Delete the driver software for this device" and click OK
5. After it completes the process, restart the computer
6. When the Windows desktop loads, an icon should appear in the notification area indicating that it is installing a device driver.  Let Windows find the driver itself.
7. Disconnect the network cable from the computer, connect to your router from the network icon in the notification area, and try accessing websites again.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I tested the connection for a while and I didn't experience any other problem! Thank you very much!